# python strong/weak dynamic/static type language?

Tags: python, types, strong-typing

l learned that **Python** is **strong-dynamic** typed language.
**dynamic**: type of a variable is determined at *execution* time NOT *compiling* time. For this part, I can understand that type is determined when a value(type of course) is assigned to the variable.

**strong**: you can NOT change the type of a variable.
But this is not the real case:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a = 's'
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
```

From the code above, I can change the type of variable a from *int* to *str*.
How can this happen? Could I say Python is a weak-typed language?

---

***EDIT:***

If you can give me a code snippet that shows **how strong-dynamic typing affect** Python programming, I would appreciate it pretty much!
During my usual coding, I never care about the **strong-dynamic typing** issues. It seldom affects my code function as well. Weird!

---

***EDIT:***
Conclusion from the answers:

1. Only object/value has type attribute. Variable has no type.
2. (Strong) Type determines what operations can be performed
   over/between objects/values (maybe variables referring to them).
3. (Dynamic) Type means variable just a label (reference to
   object/value). This label can refer to any object/value of any type.

Comment: strong (or weak) typing is *not* related to the "type of a *variable* [or expression]", but rather the operations [and implicit conversions] allowed on or between *values*

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that an object retains its type no matter what you do to it.  An int is an int is an int; a str is a str; a float is a float.  In a weakly typed language, you can do something like

```
i = "1" 
j = i + 2
```

and get j == 3.  In python, you get

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

A str is always a str, and can't be treated as an int even if the string contains a number.

Try this:

```
for a in {1, 'abc', 3.14159}:
    print a
    print type(a)
```

which will produce

```
3.14159
<type 'float'>
1
<type 'int'>
abc
<type 'str'>
```

A single variable can be set to refer to any type of object - that's the "dynamic" part of it.  But the object is always of the same type no matter how you refer to it - that's the "strong" part of it.

Comment: A JavaScript "object retains its type" as well. Yet JavaScript is considered weakly-typed: thus strong/weak typing is *not* merely that an "x is an x". (The expression `"1" + 2` does not change the type of any value in either Python or JavaScript.)

Comment: The example of the failing code is correct (and I would argue this absence of presence of implicit conversions is a lynch-pin), but most of the rest is a poor argument for strong typing. In JavaScript `[1,"foo",{}].map(function (v) { return typeof v; })` yields `["number","string","object"]` which entirely negates the ancillary argument made.

Comment: The question was about Python.  I have only trivial experience with Javascript, so I made no attempt to describe or reference it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing the **type** of the variable so much as reassigning `a` which was an `int` to a now brand new variable by the same name, which is a `str`

Answer (score 2):

When you reassign a new value to a variable, I wouldn't say it is the "same" variable, since it's identifier will change. Look at this example:

```
a = 1
print id(a)
a = 2
print id(a)
a = "asd"
print id(a)
```

prints in my machine:

```
30925512
30925488
37467840
```

it means `a` is no longer the same object. From [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id):

> **id(object)** Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime.

Comment: I never used **id(object)** statement before. Your explanation is somewhat persuasive from a different point.

Comment: @Zachary It is the same *variable* (in so far the only way to access a variable is with a *name* in a particular scope). It simply evaluates to a different *value*. The `id` relates to the *value/object* (which *results from the evaluation of the variable-expression*) and thus cannot be used to say anything about the variable otherwise.

Comment: DO you mean this _id()_ function is not useful in code? How can make use of it?

Comment: @Zachary It is rarely useful in normal code. The value it returns is an *opaque identifier* for the object. It has nothing to do with typing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more accurate to say that Python is strongly typed because you cannot change the type of an *object*.  Python variables are somewhat different from those in many other languages because they are nothing but names pointing to objects.  Names themselves contain no type information, only objects do.

In a weakly-typed language like JavaScript, you can do something like `1 == "1"` and get a true result, or do `3 - "2"` and get 1, because the objects implicitly coerce between integer and string; an object's type is not "part of its identity", and objects behave like different types according to the context.  In Python you can't do such things; if you want to make one type act like another, you have to actually create a new object of a new type, because an object's type is intrinsic to the object.

Comment: So, variables in Python are *like* most other languages because variables [of types that are not represented as immediate values] are nothing but names pointing to objects .. :) Python just avoids some of the name baggage and implementation-talk.

Comment: @user2864740: I don't know how you'd evaluate "most", but I don't really agree with what you say there.  In a language like C++, a variable is not just a label for an object, it also represents the storage of that object, so in C++ doing something like `a = b` can copy `b`.  In Python doing `a = b` just adds `a` as a label pointing to the object `b` points to and nothing is copied.  Also, in such languages, types are associated with names, not only with values.

Comment: BreBarn, so that means， in Python， we cannot get the address of a variable like in C++ &a.

Comment: Once `T*` is introduced in C/C++/Obj-C (that is, where the variable is nothing but an indirect lookup), the end-result of just being name applies quite well. Java, C#, Scala, etc, effectively treat all "reference" types T as "T*" implicitly. Many other dynamic languages such as JavaScript, Ruby and ST arguably have a similar definition of variables/bindings as Python. (It doesn't matter is a type is associated with a variable, that's only a binding restriction: `object v`.)

Comment: @Zachary You cannot. But you can't do that in Java or C# (without unsafe) either.